# generating hybrid *.py file from 2 other files

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to write a python script that can combine two python files into a hybrid that overwrites methods from the first file using methods from a second file (those methods can be standalone, or exist inside a class).

For example, say I have original.py:

```
from someclass import Class0

def fun1(a, b):
    print "fun1", a, b

def fun2(a):
    print "fun2", a

class Class1(Class0):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print "init", a

    def fun3(self, a, b):
        print "fun3", a, b
```

and new.py:

```
def fun2(a, b):
    print "new fun2", a, b

class Class1(Class0):
    def fun3(self, a, b):
        print "new fun3"
```

and after running combine('original.py', 'new.py') I want it to generate a new file that looks as follows:

```
import someclass

def fun1(a, b):
    print "fun1", a, b

def fun2(a, b):
    print "new fun2", a, b

class Class1:
    def __init__(self, a):
        print "init", a

    def fun3(self, a, b):
        print "new fun3"
```

I'm trying to figure out what's the cleanest way to approach this. I was thinking of using regex at first, but keeping track of indentations and current level I'm in (a method inside a class would be one level deep, but what if a file has classes inside classes or methods inside other methods as happens when using decorators) sounds like a disaster waiting to happen. I was also thinking of using tokenize module to generate a syntax tree, and then trying to navigate to the same element in both trees, replacing portions of one tree with parts of another (again this seems like it could get complicated since all uses of tokenize I see are for modifying individual python tokens rather than entire methods). What do you guys suggest? It seems like a simple task, but I don't see a clean way of accomplishing it.

Also, I don't care if the second file is complete or valid (note the missing import despite inheritance from Class0), although if making the second file valid would allow me to use some internal python trick (like modifying python import logic to overwrite imported methods using ones from different file and then dumping the imported version from memory into a new file), then I'd be fine with that as well.

**EDIT (more explanation about why I'm trying to do this rather than using inheritance):**

I guess my question needs to better explain why I'm trying to do this. I have several groups/customers I'm providing my source code to. The functionality needs to differ based on customer requirements (in some cases it's something simple like tweaking the parameters file, like sarnold mentioned; in others the users are asking for features/hooks that are irrelevant to other groups, and would only add more confusion to the UI). Additionally, some of the source code is customer-specific and/or proprietary (so while I can share it with some groups, I'm not allowed to share it with others), this is what makes me try to avoid inheritance. I guess I can still rely on normal inheritance as long as it's the subclass version that's proprietary and not the original but for most features currently there is only one group that doesn't have the priveledges (and it's not always the same group for each feature) and the other groups do. So if I was to use inheritance, I'd probably need a bunch of directories/files like "SecretFromA", "SecretFromB", ..., "SecretFromZ" and then for each of the other groups I'd need "from SecretFromZ import *" for every module, whereas with the replacement technique I described I can just add stubs for functionality I want to filter. This is also something I'd be using in the future a lot, so as painful as it would be to write this script now, I feel like I will save a lot more in the future by not having to maintain the plethora of "from * import *" type files that inheritance would force on me (not to mention having to diff each version later in the event that customer decides to move features around).

Also, in response to comment from sarnold, I guess I was too vague in my description. This is not something that would happen on the fly. I'd generate the new *.py files once (per version/delivery) and give the generated source to the customer. Additionally the patching would only take place if the second file (new.py in my example) actually exists, otherwise the original would be copied over. So unlike with inheritance, my group-specific directories would be relatively small, with the final version being deployed to a separate directory that I wouldn't need to maintain at all aside from delivering it to the customer.

Comment: "I'm trying to figure out what's the cleanest way to approach this." -- The cleanest approach certainly is not to do this at all.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This can be done with a lot of effort... Chances are there are better ways to accomplish whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: Since this isn't answering your exact question, I'm making it a comment. DON'T DO THIS. Instead, have `original.py` define a class, and have `new.py` define a class that inherits the class from `original.py`. Then you can override the methods you want (or even undefine them if that's what you feel like doing). This is exactly why classes exist, don't re-invent the wheel poorly.

Comment: I have a project I started a while back and now got to the point where I need multiple variations of it, but don't want to have multiple copies of same file that vary very little or have hundreds of files that just say "from __SameName__ import *", since then I'd have to open up each file individually to see which ones actually differ. Also, in response to Sven, if that's the approach we'd take to every problem, we'd still be in stone age.

Comment: @user507, I think you misunderstood @sven's advice, and I think he wasn't very precise in stating it. :) What is the _problem_ you are trying to solve with this solution? When I hear that you're intending to have several hundred different classes all patched together with `diff(1)` rather than a class inheritance mechanism, I have to think that (a) your differences can probably be described via _data_ that _configures your classes_, or (b) several hundred derived classes probably is still a cleaner solution than patching on the fly. I'm really curious what you're trying to solve. :)

Comment: @user:  Your actual problem is not "merging two Python files".  Your problem is rather what you described in the last comment, and "merging two Python files" is a proposed solution.  A clean approach would be to write the code flexible enough that you don't need multiple variations.

Comment: @sarnold, @Chris, @Sven: you're right in that inheritance is usually a better way to go. I didn't think to add the extra detail explaining why I'd prefer to avoid inheritance, my bad. I've added additional information to my question. Sorry if I sound bullheaded, but in the long run it feels like inheritance would make things harder to maintain for me. If you guys think there is some inheritance functionality I'm not seeing (that would prevent me from having to use a bunch of nearly-blank import files), I'm open to suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your new improved description I can propose a solution that I've used in the past, as well as other teams, to great effect: use your source control to manage the differences via branches or new repositories.

First things first, please use a [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system of some sort. The more advanced ones, such as [`git`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), [`hg`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial), [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion), [Bazaar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar_%28software%29), [ClearCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_ClearCase), [BitKeeper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitKeeper), [Darcs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcs), [Perforce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce), etc., all support some form of *merge tracking* that can make this specific problem significantly easier to solve. (Whether or not you decide to use branches this way, please do use a source control system.)

You would maintain a main branch (call it *trunk* or *master* if you wish) with almost all your development work, bug fixing, and so on. Branch from this all the code specific to given customers. You might prefer to branch based on *features* rather than on customer *names*, as you might have ten customers who need SCTP support, and the other twenty customers want TCP support instead. (And you want to charge more for the more exotic protocol -- so just merging it all into a configuration option would be Bad For Business.)

When it comes time to deliver new products, you change branches (or repositories) to the specialized branches, `git pull` (different repositories) or `git merge` (different branches), or `svn merge` or similar commands to pull updates from your main development trunk into your specialized branches. Depending upon if you worked on code that conflicts or not, you might have some merge conflicts to repair, or it might go very cleanly. Fix up any merge conflicts, commit to your branch, and move on to the next branch.

You're liable to wind up with a "tree" that looks something like this:

```
             I--J--K      supremely magic feature
            /     /
     D--E--F--L--M--N     magic feature
    /        /     /
A--B--C--G--H--O--P--Q    main trunk
```

Getting too many branches is one quick path to madness; be sure to commit bug fixes and shared features into main trunk if you can, and if you can't, as close to it as possible. That will make merging it back into all descendant branches much easier. It would probably be best to do all the merging as close to when you write the new feature of bug fix, as it would be freshest in your mind at that time.

Maintaining multiple versions of code can drive you insane, though -- when you can make your code more modular, and simply deliver different 'modules' of code to your users, you can drastically reduce the complexity you need to manage. Programming to a modularized interface takes discipline, and the amount of up-front work can be prohibitive, but it is often easier to manage one tool with five plugins than `5! == 120` different combinations of those five features for your customers who would pick and choose among the five features.

You'll come to recognize the sorts of modifications that make most sense in a per-customer branch and the modifications that should be maintained as modules in your trunk. The case isn't always clear-cut: take the approach that leads to lowest amount of overall complexity, as best you can judge.